# PyQt5 dynamic creation/destruction of widgets

Tags: python, widget, pyqt5

I have an application where upon start up the user is presented with a dialog to chose number of 'objects' required. This then generates necessary objects in the main window using a for loop (i.e. object1, object2, etc.). I want to move this selection into the main window so that this can be changed without the need to restart the application. I have no idea how to approach this as I'm not sure how to dynamically create/destroy once the application is running. Here's an example code that generates tabs in a tab widget with some elements in each tab.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class SelectionWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.settings = QSettings('Example', 'Example')
        self.numberOfTabs = QSpinBox(value = self.settings.value('numberOfTabs', type=int, defaultValue = 3), minimum = 1)
        self.layout = QFormLayout(self)
        self.button = QPushButton(text = 'OK', clicked = self.buttonClicked)
        self.layout.addRow('Select number of tabs', self.numberOfTabs)
        self.layout.addRow(self.button)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        self.settings.setValue('numberOfTabs', self.numberOfTabs.value())
        self.accept()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.settings = QSettings('Example', 'Example')
        self.tabs = self.settings.value('numberOfTabs', type = int)
        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget()

        for i in range(1, self.tabs + 1):
            exec(('self.tab{0} = QWidget()').format(i))
            exec(("self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab{0}, 'Tab{0}')").format(i))
            exec(('self.lineEdit{0} = QLineEdit()').format(i))
            exec(('self.spinBox{0} = QSpinBox()').format(i))
            exec(('self.checkBox{0} = QCheckBox()').format(i))
            exec(('self.layout{0} = QFormLayout(self.tab{0})').format(i))
            exec(("self.layout{0}.addRow('Name', self.lineEdit{0})").format(i))
            exec(("self.layout{0}.addRow('Value', self.spinBox{0})").format(i))
            exec(("self.layout{0}.addRow('On/Off', self.checkBox{0})").format(i))

        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabWidget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = SelectionWindow()
    dialog.show()

    if dialog.exec_() == SelectionWindow.Accepted:
        mainwindow = MainWindow()
        mainwindow.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: in all languages you have `list` or `dictionary` to keep it  - ie `self.tab = list()` , `self.tab.append(QWidget())` or `self.tab = dict()` , `self.tab[i] = QWidget()`. Similar with other elements.

Comment: maybe you should create own widget with all these elements and then you will have to add and remove own widget instead all these elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should never use `exec` for things like these. Besides the security issues of using `exec`, it also makes your code less readable (and then much harder to debug) and hard to interact with.

A better (and more "elegant") solution is to use a common function to create tabs and, most importantly, [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr).

Also, you shouldn't use QSettings in this way, as it is mostly intended for cross-session persistent data, not to initialize an interface. For that case, you should just override the `exec()` method of the dialog and initialize the main window with that value as an argument.
And, even if it was the case (but I suggest you to avoid the above approach anyway), remember that to make settings persistent, at least `organizationName` and `applicationName` *must* be set.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.settings = QSettings('Example', 'Example')
        # this value does not need to be a persistent instance attribute
        tabCount = self.settings.value('numberOfTabs', type = int)

        # create a main widget for the whole interface
        central = QWidget()
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout(central)

        tabCountSpin = QSpinBox(minimum=1)
        mainLayout.addWidget(tabCountSpin)
        tabCountSpin.setValue(tabCount)
        tabCountSpin.valueChanged.connect(self.tabCountChanged)

        self.tabWidget = QTabWidget()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)

        for t in range(tabCount):
            self.createTab(t)

        self.setCentralWidget(central)

    def createTab(self, t):
        t += 1
        tab = QWidget()
        self.tabWidget.addTab(tab, 'Tab{}'.format(t))
        layout = QFormLayout(tab)

        # create all the widgets
        lineEdit = QLineEdit()
        spinBox = QSpinBox()
        checkBox = QCheckBox()
        # add them to the layout
        layout.addRow('Name', lineEdit)
        layout.addRow('Value', spinBox)
        layout.addRow('On/Off', checkBox)

        # keeping a "text" reference to the widget is useful, but not for
        # everything, as tab can be accessed like this:
        # tab = self.tabWidget.widget(index)
        # and so its layout:
        # tab.layout()
        setattr(tab, 'lineEdit{}'.format(t), lineEdit)
        setattr(tab, 'spinBox{}'.format(t), spinBox)
        setattr(tab, 'checkBox{}'.format(t), checkBox)

    def tabCountChanged(self, count):
        if count == self.tabWidget.count():
            return
        elif count < self.tabWidget.count():
            while self.tabWidget.count() > count:
                # note that I'm not deleting the python reference to each object;
                # you should use "del" for both the tab and its children
                self.tabWidget.removeTab(count)
        else:
            for t in range(self.tabWidget.count(), count):
                self.createTab(t)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! I wasn't aware of setattr, I've only been writing code for a few months now. I just got one question, how do I keep track of the python references for the objects within the tab as I need to access them later? If these are not deleted, would they just keep piling up if I delete/create tabs?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, they will "pile up", potentially unnecessarily increasing the memory usage. In my example, the reference is based on the tab that contains the child widgets, so you could get the tab widget reference *before* removing it (tab = `self.tabWidget.widget(index)`) and use `childWidget = getattr(tab, widgetName)`, and finally `del childWidget`. Note that I did use index referencing in child widget names, but since they are already children of a child widget, you don't actually need that, so you could just use `setattr(tab, 'spinBox', spinBox)`, etc.

Comment: I have encountered a problem with this. If I change the number of tabs by using the up/down arrows (i.e. by +/- 1) then it works, however, if I just type in a number it totally breaks it. This only seems to happen when reducing the number of tabs. For example, if I start off with 5 tabs and enter 2, I end up with 'Tab 1', 'Tab 2' and 'Tab 4'.

Comment: @Vlad I fixed it using a while loop instead of for, this will always remove the first tab that exceeds the maximum count until the correct count is reached.

Comment: I actually managed to fix it myself by using getattr and then w.indexOf(target) to remove precisely the tab that corresponds to 'tab{t}'. Thanks for looking into this though.